# Cloud Formation Template: 403 while files are copied from private S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Need Help. Trying to create Windows EC2 with Java installed using below template. However, I get 403 when artifacts are being copied from my Private S3 Bucket. Role to Access S3 and EC2 instance are created fine. What could be the issue?

```
Resources:

  EC2S3Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
            Principal:
              Service: ec2.amazonaws.com
            Effect: Allow
            Sid: ''
      Policies:
        - PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - 's3:GetObject'
                Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::windowsartifcats"
                Effect: Allow
          PolicyName: AuthenticatedS3GetObjects
          
  EC2S3InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - !Ref EC2S3Role
          
  JavaSeleniumEC2Instance:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Instance"
    Properties:
      KeyName: "windowskeypair"
      ImageId: ami-0229f7666f517b31e
      InstanceType: "t2.micro"
      SecurityGroups:
        - "windows"
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref EC2S3InstanceProfile
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Join
                    - ""
                    - - "<script> cfn-init.exe -v -s "
                      - !Ref "AWS::StackId"
                      - " -r JavaSeleniumEC2Instance --region "
                      - !Ref "AWS::Region"
                      - "</script>"
    
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
          S3AccessCreds:
            Type: "S3"
            buckets:
              - "windowsartifcats"
            roleName:
              !Ref EC2S3Role
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
          config:
            files:
              "c:\\Install-Java-JDK.ps1":
                content: !Join
                  - ''
                  - - 'Set-Location C:\\;'
                    - '.\\jdk-11.0.9_windows-x64_bin.exe /s'
              "c:\\jdk-11.0.9_windows-x64_bin.exe":
                source: "https://windowsartifcats.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/jdk-11.0.9_windows-x64_bin.exe"
              "c:\\IEDriverServer.exe":
                source: "https://windowsartifcats.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/IEDriverServer.exe"

            commands:
              "JavaInstall":
                command: "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command c:\\Install-Java-JDK.ps1"
                waitAfterCompletion: '180'
```

Logs from C:\cfn\log.cfn-init:

2020-12-21 06:28:15,608 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of config: Failed to retrieve https://windowsartifcats.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/IEDriverServer.exe: HTTP Error 403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `EC2S3Role` is incorrect. The following

```
Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::windowsartifcats"
```

refers to bucket only, not its objects. To be able to download objects in your bucket, it should be:

```
Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::windowsartifcats/*"
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I changed the role to include "/*" after S3 bucket's name. I still see the same issue.

Comment: @user11833133 Do you need to use `AWS::CloudFormation::Init`? Usually it complicates a lot of things, and just using `UserData` could be easier?

Comment: Marcin, I need to copy Java.exe, IEDriver jars and install them. Also need to run Powershell scripts to set Proxy and change Internet options in Windows. Not sure if just using "UserData" will get me setup all the configurations I need. Any other options I have?

Comment: Finally the issue is fixed. Root cause to get 403 is I used "S3AccessCreds" instead of "rolebased"